# How do we know -273.15 centigrade is 0 kelvin?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am in no way doubting that humans know that -273.15 centigrade is 0 Kelvin. I'm just curious.

Suppose you know only two things:

1. A new scale for temperature known as the centigrade scale, calibrated against the freezing and boiling points of water using nifty glass thermometers (or any other standard thermometer for that matter).
2. Thermodynamics as it was in the mid 1800's - i.e. knowledge that temperature **should** be a strictly positive quantity.

How do you go from knowing those two things to saying "Aha! I have now inferred that absolute zero-temperature in the modern thermodynamic sense is, on the centigrade scale, at -273.15!"

Comment: Hint: show the temperature of an object at 0C is 273.15 K. Then use 1K=1C by definition.

Comment: What would happen if you plotted the $V$ vs $T$ relationship with various gasses where $T$ is in Celsius?

Comment: Of course, in @BowlOfRed 's experiment, the pressure should be held constant.

Comment: The kelvin was originally defined in 1954 by designating the triple point of water as its second defining point and assigned its temperature to exactly 273.16 K. Later it was redefined such that "The kelvin, unit of thermodynamic temperature, is equal to the fraction 1⁄273.16 of the thermodynamic temperature of the triple point of water." There are moves afoot to redefine the Kelvin  as the temperature scale for which Boltzmann's constant is $1.3806505 \times10^{−23}$ J/K exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how a precise value would have been obtained circa 1800's. Here's how I had my Chemistry students derive an approximate value with simple equipment.

The apparatus is a hollow steel ball about 10 cm in diameter connected to a pressure gauge. Also involved is a thermometer capable of -70 C to 100 C.

The bulb of this apparatus is then immersed in boiling water, ice water and a mixture of dry ice and acetone. The temperature and pressure are recorded for each treatment. Then the presure is plotted versus the temperature. Since P is proportional to T, a linear plot results. When the plot is extrapolated to P = 0, the temperature is reasonably close to -273 C.

Since temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the particles, the thermodynamic temperature should be zero when the particles stop moving. When the particles are no longer moving the pressure should then become zero as well.

Comment: This theory would hold together great if there were no phase changes for the gas between -70 C and absolute zero.

Comment: There is no "theory" here, merely application of the Ideal Gas Law and the definitions of temperature and pressure.  The only way phase transitions would matter is by attempting to gather data points too low for the gas used.  Air behaves relatively ideally at the temperatures used in the experiment. But, conceptually, the gas we're cooling to 0K is an ideal gas, not air. No intermolecular attractions to invoke phase changes.

Comment: You did your tests on real gases, not ideal gases.  Even though the ideal gas law is a good approximation for the temperature range you considered, extrapolating this to -273 is not a very convincing way of showing that the kinetic energies of real substances go to zero at absolute zero (in my judgment).

Comment: Thousands of my students have been convinced. As have, I suspect, tens of thousands of others. The graph really is, if not precise, pretty convincing. And very doable in the 1800's which was my intrepretation of the OP's quiestion. I also intrepreted the question as asking how to arrive at the value in Celsius, not as proof that the kinetic energy of a real substance would be zero at 0K. I (we, including other Chemistry teachers) use that as an axiom inherent in the Ideal Gas Law and a consequence of the thermodynamic definition of temperature, at least as it was back then.

Comment: If the same extrapolation works for a number of real gases, that is persuasive.

Comment: As long as all the gases tested are tested within the range of approximate ideal behavior, they should behave similiarly. Of course, as @Miller implies, the assumptions of the IGL do not apply near 0K when the intermolecular forces between particles become relevant. But as you suggest, given enough time in the classroom, an additional trial with another gas would be a great way to test the fundamental tenet of the IGL. That is, that it applies to all gasses when behaving ideally. Helium would be fun to work with, parental permission slips might be required.

Comment: My thought was that, if a condensed phase formed along the cooling path, the P vs T behavior would change for the constant volume system.  However, after further consideration, I feel that it is possible to start out at a low enough gas pressure that a condensed phase would not form until temperatures very close to absolute zero are reached.  This would largely negate my earlier objection to what you were saying.  I wonder if anyone else has anything to add regarding the behavior of gases at very low pressures and temperatures.

Comment: I'd love to find a cite proving it, but I think this is historically accurate as well. We had the full set of gas laws by the early 1800s, and they were derived by experiments very much like this. What remains is to look at (e.g.) Dalton's data and ponder on what it means for the fitted line to cross zero.

Comment: At the time it was (correctly) understood that that was unphysical and a gas would stop acting like a gas at a low enough temperature. But if you start to develop something like a kinetic theory of gases, then that justifies thinking about absolute zero as a real thing.